# React-native error: Metro bundler can't listener on 8081?

Tags: react-native

I'm using react-native latest version and get the following error:

[image]

How can I resolve this error? Thanks!

Comment: Check if your port 8081 is already in use by other applications, or is there any chance you run the react-native twice?

Comment: node use port 8081, and i kill the process, restart 'react-native run-ios', iphone6 is white, and not 'bundling index.js [development, non-minified]  100.0% (487/487), done. ', see here [link](http://oo8hp4ueg.bkt.clouddn.com/%E5%B1%8F%E5%B9%95%E5%BF%AB%E7%85%A7%202017-12-15%20%E4%B8%8A%E5%8D%8811.59.07.png)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

lsof -i :8081

kill -9 PID_FROM_ABOVE

react-native start

.....

Comment: Should be `lsof -i :8081`. Note the different port.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the port is being used by another process.Simple solution for this problem.

1. Close all the terminal instances
2. Open iOS folder and delete build file
3. re run the project

It will work like a charm